# Azure storage service architecture

Tags: azure, storage, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files

I am using Azure storage service for my application

I need to store some organisation data like images, documents, videos etc for my application.
In my application user from 50 organisations upload their data.

We have following concerns

1) each company will use only 10 GB space. If their user-data exceeds 10 GB then there will be no access for storage.
   Is it feasible?

2) What is best architecture we can design? For example I have container for each 5 organisations and year folder like 2018/2017 and then sub-folders inside each years like image/doc/videos
   So I will have 5 container then years folder with 3 sub-folders each.

Heirarchy will like
   organisation (container) - > year (folder) - > three sub-folders (image/doc/videos)
   Then is it possible to restrict/grant access to years (folder)?

Please suggest?

Comment: That's a lot of questions in one post, where some will most probably give you primarily opinion based answers. That's not a suitable question for SO. Please refer to the [don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) article.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits

Comment: I have reduced question number and size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have abstracted three questions from your revised question (I think)

1. Can we limit a storage account container to a specific size (like 10 GB)?  (Or is there an approach we can implement to achieve this)

*No there is no ability to set a quota on a given container in a storage account.   To do that you will need to implement the size check business logic in an API that is fronting the storage account and containers.*

2. What architecture is suggested given the data provided? (organization, year, type, etc.)

*The container structure suggested will work as long as you implement an API above it for controlling access and to enforce business rules and storage placement.*

3. Can you restrict/grant access to containers in the Azure storage account (aka folders)?

*You have to use SAS tokens if you want to secure containers in an Azure storage account.  Broadly speaking with your requirements you need to look at implementing a middle-man service like an API (through Functions / API Management / Logic Apps) that will implement your storage routing, business logic and security rules*.